# nexti18-next translation not being displayed

Tags: next.js, i18next, next-i18next

With my latest prod deployment, for some reason my translations aren't being displayed.

I see that the file is loaded and that the translation is present.

[image]

But it seems that the translation isn't being found.

[image]

Update: Seems this is the same on local. But I don't see any errors.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the order is important. Could be because my description json file is large, so needs to take priority.

From this:
[Image before change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqtCl.png)

To this:
[Image after change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yj7yC.png)